# Cygwin and Apache Pig - a perplexing pseudo-grunt>

Tags: cygwin, apache-pig

I'm trying to get a working installation of Apache Pig on a Windows PC running the Vista operating system, in order to use it as a learning tool; I don't intend to do any serious data processing with Pig on this machine. A single node, single JVM `-x local` setup is what I want.

I come from a Windows background, so UNIX is the big learning curve for me, but following advice in the online Apache Pig documentation *Getting Started*, I have installed cygwin and it seems to be working fine. I included the Perl package in my cygwin download and installation, as advised in *Getting Started*, and that seems to be working fine as well - the /bin directory contains perl.exe and I can access all the Perl documentation.

I then downloaded pig-0.11.1, unpacked it with `tar -xzvf pig-0.11.1.tar.gz` and spent a few (mostly enjoyable) days using the errors I got when trying `pig -x local` to study the Bash Reference Manual and go through the pig shell script, which I think I now pretty much understand. Having adjusted calls to the cygwin utility `cygpath` in this script, so that pig.jar is found and the arguments passed to java.exe remain converted by `cygpath` to a form that java.exe can understand, I get a grunt prompt. But my whoops of joy have been short-lived.

In fact, I get the same grunt prompt with pig-0.7.0 downloaded, installed and used out-of-the-box, with `pig -x local`, as RELEASE_NOTES.txt describes, without any tampering with its pig shell script at all. But unfortunately it is the *same* grunt prompt I get with pig-0.11.1: a curious, pseudo-grunt prompt where the arrow keys can move the cursor all over the prompt, in fact all around the screen, over previous commands given at the dollar prompt even, and the return key (preceded by ;) does nothing but jump the cursor to a new line. Text can be written but not entered, and only ^c and ^\ seem to work - mercifully returning the bash dollar prompt and a little sanity.

- From my pig-0.7.0 directory, typing `bin/pig -help` gives a proper readout:

  ```
  Apache Pig version 0.7.0 (r941408)<br />
  compiled May 05 2010, 11:15:55<br />
  USAGE: Pig [options] [-] : Run interactively in grunt shell.</br >
     Pig [options] -e[xecute] cmd [cmd ...] : Run cmd(s).<br />
  Pig [options] [-f[ile]] file : Run cmds found in file.
  options include: ... *etc etc*<br />
  ```
- From my pig-0.7.0 directory, typing `bin/pig -x local` results in the following response:

  ```
  13/04/18 10:37:51 INFO pig.Main: Logging error messages to: C:\cygwin\home\Richard\pig_installation\pig-0.7.0\pig_1366277871311.log<br />
  2013-04-18 10:37:51,540 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///<br />
  ```
- From any directory, since I have set PATH to my pig-0.11.1/bin directory, typing `pig -x local` results in the following response:

  ```
  which: no hadoop in (usr/local/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files ... *etc etc* .. )<br />
  2013-04-18 10:48:59,946 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1 (r1459641) compiled Mar 22 2013, 02:13:53<br />
  2013-04-18 10:48:59,946 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: C:\cygwin\home\Richard\pig_installation\pig-0.7.0\pig_1366278539943.log<br />
  2013-04-18 10:48:59,965 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file C:\Users\Richard/.pigbootup not found<br />
  2013-04-18 10:49:01,404 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///<br />
  ```

Is this a fatal error or am I just missing a trick? The pig shell script in pig-0.11.1 seems to imply that if hadoop is not found, pig.jar or pig-?.!(*withouthadoop).jar (e.g. pig-0.11.1.jar) will do instead, and the documentation tells me that pig on Windows with cygwin is supported (for `-x local` but not `-x mapreduce`). Is this pseudo-grunt> prompt a complete mirage, or does it indicate partial success?

- Postscript to the above: I've followed the section Pig Tutorial in Apache's Pig documentation *Getting Started*, set the environment variables, edited the pig-0.7.0/tutorial/build.xml file as per instructions, run the `ant` command, created the pigtutorial.tar.gz file, moved it, unzipped it, found pig script 1 and run `pig -x local script1-local.pig` and IT WORKS! The output file - part-r-00000 - contains no warnings at all, just five columns of records, as expected. A new attempt to get interactive mode, however, with `pig -x local`, results in the same pseudo-grunt> prompt.

Comment: I had some "success" installing Pig using the  method described by this guy:  https://itellity.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/setting-up-hadoop-on-windows-vista/.   However, when I type any command into the grunt prompt, even 'help' or 'describe' it just hangs forever, no log messages produced, so...  I'm still stuck, but it wasn't anywhere near as painful as the lengths you went to there.