# Pig in grunt mode

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, apache-pig, gruntjs

I have installed cygwin, hadoop and pig in windows. The configuration seems ok, as I can run pig scripts in batch and embedded mode.

When I try to run pig in grunt mode, something strange happens. Let me explain.
I try to run a simple command like

```
grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

When I press Enter, nothing happens. The cursor goes to the next line and the `grunt>` prompt does not appear at all anymore. It seems as I am typing in a text editor.

Has anything similar ever happened to you? Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running a legacy MapReduce program like word count etc.? Does that work fine?

Comment: Hello,
"Word counts" works fine when run in batch pig script (and local mode). When I try to run it in grunt mode, on pressing enter after the first pig command, (as in grunt>A = load './input.txt';) nothing at all happens.

Comment: This may be a bug. Someone else reported the same problem in another question; see the last comment in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081246/cygwin-and-apache-pig-a-perplexing-pseudo-grunt).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is consistent with what you are observing. I will take the [pig tutorial](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/tutorial.html#Pig+Script+1%3a+Query+Phrase+Popularity) for example.

The following command does not result in any activity by `pig`.

```
raw = LOAD 'excite.log' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (user, time, query);
```

But if you invoke a command that results in using data from variable `raw` using some map-reduce thats when you will see some action in your grunt shell. Some thing along the lines of second command that is mentioned there.

```
clean1 = FILTER raw BY org.apache.pig.tutorial.NonURLDetector(query);
```

Similarly, your command will not result in any action, you have to use the data from variable `A` which results in map-reduce command to see some action on grunt shell:

```
grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

Comment: I have run the script from this example in batch mode and it works perfectly ($ java -Xms2048m -cp pig.jar org.apache.pig.Main -x local script1-local.pig
). When in grunt mode however, as soon as I press enter after the first command, the <grunt> particle disappears and the rest of the pig commands are entered as in the image. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mpfyiga3pf7o5cm/oWyiWZTv6A#f:grunt_tutorial_script.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Pig will only process the commands when you use a command that creates output namely `DUMP` (to console) or `STORE` you can also use command `DESCRIBE` to get the structure of an alias and `EXPLAIN` to see the map/reduce plan

so basically `DUMP A;` will give you all the records in A

Comment: I have tried that, but nothing happens. This is the screenshot from the grunt shell when I type the exact same functions that seem to work quite well in batch mode. <br/> 
www.dropbox.com/sh/mpfyiga3pf7o5cm/oWyiWZTv6A#f:grunt_test_script.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run in the windows command window.

> C:\FAST\JDK64\1.6.0.31/bin/java -Xmx1000m -Dpig.log.dir=C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/logs -Dpig.log.file=pig.log -Dpig.home.dir=C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/ -classpath C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/conf;C;C:/FAST/JDK64/1.6.0.31/lib/tools.jar;C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar;C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/conf;C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/hadoop/conf;C:/cygwin/home/$USERNAME$/nubes/pig/pig-0.11.1.jar org.apache.pig.Main -x local

Replace `$USERNAME$` with your user id accordingly ..

Modify the class path and conf path accordingly ..

It works well in both local as well as map reduce mode ..

Answer (score 0):

Pig shell hangs up in cygwin. But pig script successfully executed from pig script file.

As below:

```
$pig ./user/input.txt
```

For local mode:

```
pig -x local ./user/input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem as you yesterday，and I spent one whole day to find what was wrong with my pig or my hotkey and fix it finally. I found that it's only because I copied the pig code from other resource，then the bending quotation marks cannot be identified in pig command line, which only admits straight quotation marks, so the input stream would not end. 
My suggestion is that you should take care of the valid characters in the code, especially when you just copy codes into the command line, which always causes unexpected faults.